# Кто поможет с string.replace (JS)?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, foreach, match

```
    // Исходная строка
    let string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor, dolor sit amet, amet consectetur adipisicing elit';
    let regex = /dolor/g; // искомая подстрока (может быть каким угодно регулярным выражением, не в нём суть)
    let m;
    // Если массив совпадений не пуст:
    if ((m = string.match(regex)) !== null) {
        // Пройдёмся по полученному массиву совпадений и заменим все совпадения, на их жирное начертание
        m.forEach(match => {
            string = string.replace(match, `<b>${match}</b>`);
        });
    }
    console.log(string); // `Lorem ipsum <b><b>dolor</b></b>, dolor sit amet, amet consectetur adipisicing elit`
```

Почему происходит оборачивание первого совпадения два раза?

Если дело в глобальной области видимости, то при замене на:

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp(match, 'g'), `<b>${match}</b>`);
```

Результат вообще такой:
`Lorem ipsum <b><b>dolor</b></b>, <b><b>dolor</b></b> sit amet, amet consectetur adipisicing elit`

Как получить:
`Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b>, <b>dolor</b> sit amet, amet consectetur adipisicing elit`

Comment: потому что после первой замены  `Lorem ipsum dolor` на `Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b>` - следующая замена опять найдет именно этот dolor, а не следующий

Comment: да это я и сам понимаю ... но как с этим справится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После первой замены `Lorem ipsum dolor` на `Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b>` - следующая замена опять найдет именно этот `dolor`, а не следующий.

Использовать [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) здесь не нужно, [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) вполне понимает, когда ей передают регулярное выражение.

Код может свестись к следующему:

```js
// Исходная строка
let string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor, dolor sit amet, amet consectetur adipisicing elit';
let regex = /dolor/g; // искомая подстрока (может быть каким угодно регулярным выражением, не в нём суть)
string = string.replace(regex, `<b>$&</b>`);
console.log(string);
```

Где `$&` - это подстрока полностью удовлетворяющая регулярному выражению.

При использовании групп, к ним можно обращаться как `$0`,`$1`,`$2` и т.д.

Comment: Вот спасибо тебе огромное Grundy! Я целых три дня бился, а оказалось всё очень просто! СПАСИБО!